# python urllib2: socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2, urlopen

the URL https://www.zacks.com/ works in my browser, and I can also access it from Go, why does the server close the connection for Python?

I am using python 2.7.15.

```
import urllib2

page = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.zacks.com/')
```

is giving following error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 3, in <module>
    page = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.zacks.com/')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\urllib2.py", line 1241, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\urllib2.py", line 1201, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\httplib.py", line 1121, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\httplib.py", line 438, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\httplib.py", line 394, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\socket.py", line 480, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\ssl.py", line 772, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\ssl.py", line 659, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len)
socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Go Program which is working fine.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    _, err := http.Get("https://www.zacks.com/")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("success")
}
```

Output:

```
success
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly? Is the error not clear? You can't force a remote server to keep a connection open, if the server is closing connections forcibly then that's the end of the road. That's not a Python issue.

Comment: I updated the title. Thanks.

Comment: I tried same thing in Go and it's working. why it is not working in python?

Comment: See, now we are getting somewhere. Can you please add that to your question? You can say something along the lines of: this URL works in my browser, and I can also access it from Go (perhaps with some code?), why does the server close the connection for Python?

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the server is looking for `User-Agent` in header to validate the request. You can add it in the request header and try:

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request(request)
req.add_header('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0')
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
content = resp.read()
print content
```

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue. How did you find out the cause?

Comment: Cool. Was looking at the request headers sent by `urllib2` and the headers sent with while in browser.